# cocos2d gradual FPS drop

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, objective-c++

Hey, im running cocos2d, box2d and several particle systems on the iPhone 4.
I've completed my first level which has numerous sprites allocated as well.
I have set my FPS limit to 30fps.
When the game first runs, it runs well, at a solid 30fps. This continues for about 3-4 minutes of smooth gameplay.
But after a while the fps starts to drop, and it turns into a gradual decline until it hits around the 12fps mark.

I remember I had this problem with a previous game that I abandoned.
Is this caused by a memory leak, possibly from not deallocating items??

In my (void)dealloc methods, I am inputting all my allocated releases, could I have missed one? Or is there some other possibility i'm not considering?

Thanks!

Comment: Try using Instruments - http://www.cimgf.com/2008/04/02/cocoa-tutorial-fixing-memory-leaks-with-instruments/

Comment: May be it is caused due to particle system.can you post your particle code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're running out of resources. I'd try Instruments as suggested by SB. Instruments can check for leaks using the Allocation instrument. You could also try the OpenGL profiling suite.

Comment: Yes, it seems you are right.  
I have 3 memory leaks :  
GeneralBlock-512 GeneralBlock-512 and NSConcreteMapTable.  
The total amount of Leaked Bytes is never-ending it doesnt stop!!
Unsure how to fix this though, ill play around.

Comment: In the Allocations instrument, you can track the alloc/retain/release/autorelease history for each allocated object. You can see the stack trace for each event. That can lead you directly to the offending code.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I cannot get the resolution. When I unload the entire scene and reload it again, everything is back to normal. So it definitely seems to be a leak somewhere, but even with instruments I cannot find the source of it.

The total memory usage is not growing, no leaks reported, so I have the feeling that something in Cocos2d or in Chipmunk increasing the load.

I am using sprites which are moving in and out from the screen in a random manner and creating nd destroying them every time. Can it be that something is not released properly and Cocos or Chipmunk is still calculating with those items?

Comment: make sure your not continually reallocing CCActions in the game loop. That was my problem

Comment: Thanks, I am doing this in the code, but I thought deallocation the item completely would deallocate the related actions. I will try to make the action upfront and and just use them where needed. Let's see.

Comment: Hi Oliver, I have found the problem. I was trying to reuse actions and animations putting them into retained variable and use them in other object. Based on your suggestion I have recoded to whole game by creating and using actions and animations at the place where they are needed. The frame rate is stably at 60fps, even when I am creating 10-12 new objects almost at the same time. I have killed all my 'retains' as those were creating memory leaks. Finally everything is seems to be perfect. Thanks again.